# Google Datastore query NodeJS application how to get ID of entities

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have a NodeJS application that is using Google Datastore. I have a basic query set up and it works to return data from the database.

Question: How can I retrieve the ID for each entity that is returned? I need the ID in the result set such that it can be displayed to the user on the UI.

Here is the NodeJS query so far. I was able to get the entire key but how do I get just the ID from the query result?

NodeJS:

```
  const treq_history = datastore.createQuery('TransferRequest');
  //Set query conditions
  treq_history.filter('requester', 'test');
  //Run datastore query
  datastore.runQuery(treq_history, function(err, entities) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Transfer Request History JSON unable to return data results for File Path. Error message: ', err);
      return;
      //If query works and returns any entities
    } else if (entities[0]) {
      //Access the Key object for an entity.
      var firstEntityKey = entities[0][datastore.KEY];

      console.log('Entity key: ', firstEntityKey);
      console.log('Entity data: ' + JSON.stringify(entities[0]));

      res.json(entities);
      return;
    } else {
      //Else if query works but does not return any entities return an empty object in JSON response
      res.json('{}');
      return;
    }
  });
```

Console output:

```
Entity key  Key {
  namespace: undefined,
  id: '5658319839738991',
  kind: 'TransferRequest',
  path: [Getter] }
Entity data: {"transfer_request_status":"Processing","created_datetime":1509395305624,"requester":"test","dataowner":"example"}
```

UPDATE:

I was able to access the ID with the key:

```
entities[0][datastore.KEY]['id']
```

Comment: unfortunately, I am unable to do the same :( 
```err=TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined```

Comment: @cmag based on that error message it looks like the entity you are trying to read is undefined. Print out the string representation of the entity you are trying to read to make sure it is defined.  console.log('Entity data: ' + JSON.stringify(entities[0]));  When you confirm it is defined then get the key like this entities[0][datastore.KEY]['id']. Hope this helps.