# Parent Entities, nodejs

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Folks,
  How does one access the parent entities?  Lets imagine I have 2 Kinds, `users` and say `cars`...  When Kind `cars` is queried by plate, it returns all the entities that match the plate.  How can one also get those entities' ancestor information?  What if I wanted to get the parent key for the returned' entities?  Is this possible?

Example where I only am able to retrieve the entities

```
const query = datastoreClient.createQuery('cars')
    .filter('plate', '=', 'ABC');
return datastoreClient.runQuery(query).then(function (entities) {
    console.log(entities);
    return entities;
});
```

output:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": "2b49ca40-a5fb-11e7-ad5c-c95aa76161c6",
            "plate": "ABC"
        }
    ],
    {
        "moreResults": "NO_MORE_RESULTS",
        "endCursor": "Cn0Sd2oWc35za2lsZnVsLWZyYW1lLTE4MDIxN3JdCxIFdXNlcnMiJDIxMmU2MTQwLWE1OTQtMTFlNy1iMGQ1LWUxNjBjMjA0NjI2MQwLEgRjYXJzIiQyYjQ5Y2E0MC1hNWZiLTExZTctYWQ1Yy1jOTVhYTc2MTYxYzYMGAAgAA=="
    }
]
```

Comment: check how `entities[0][datastore.KEY]` looks like (from https://stackoverflow.com/q/47024975/4495081). Donno about nodejs, but in python the entity key includes the entire entity ancestry as a list, easy to access any ancestor level desired from it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the Node.js code that does what you want:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const projectId = 'some-projectid'

// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
  projectId: projectId,
});

const Query = datastore
        .createQuery('cars')
        .filter('plate', '=', 'some-plate-number')

datastore.runQuery(Query).then(results => {
  // Task entities found.
  const tasks = results[0];
  console.log('Tasks:');
  tasks.forEach(task => console.log(task));
```

Output:

> Tasks: { plate: 'some-plate-number',   [Symbol(KEY)]:    Key {
>        namespace: undefined,
>        id: 'id-of-the-child-entity',
>        kind: 'cars',
>        parent:
>         Key {
>           namespace: undefined,
>           id: 'id-of-the-parent-entity',
>           kind: 'users',
>           path: [Getter] },
>        path: [Getter] } }